# Нужна ли запятая между частями сложного предложения при наличии вводного перед второй его частью?

Tags: пунктуация

*На «России 1» перестали выходить «Вести в субботу» с Сергеем Брилёвым — по официальной версии, он уехал в длительную командировку.*

Нужно ли было автору текста в СМИ поставить запятую перед тире, если правило у Розенталя гласит:

— Перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям:

Собака исчезла, — наверно, её убили (Слепц.).

Comment: Вот еще SOS на эту тему для отвечающих:  Коллеги, спасите!
Вот два предложения: "Там дураки власть берут, - может, жизнь поумнеет", "Комиссар тоже спал, лицо его сморщилось - вероятно, он мучился перед сном воспоминаниями". Нужно ли ставить запятую и тире, или тире достаточно? Буду благодарна, если приведете обоснование.

Comment: @Sharon в первом случае я бы поставил. Запятая требуется по правилу, а тире как бы отделяет выражение надежды. Во втором случае отсутствием запятой перед тире автор, по-видимому, обозначает, что пояснение *вероятно, он мучился...* относится только к сморщенному лицу, но не к тому, что комиссар спал.

Comment: @Nektoid
 Какое правило вы имеете в виду? Что тире показывает, к какой части БСП относится вводное слово? Это правило НАДУМАННОЕ, так как практически всегда ясно (по семантике или по структуре), к какой части оно относится.  Поэтому это правило на практике не используется. У Розенталя есть правило о постановке ЕДИНОГО ЗНАКА в БСП, если нужно подчеркнуть деление на две смысловые части. Оно отчасти подходит  к первому примеру. Что касается второго, то там обычное присоединение,  поэтому ставится только тире.  Относится оно к обоим предложениям, так как они связаны перечислительной интонацией.

Comment: @Sharon добавьте ещё капса, а то недостаточно понятно, что других аргументов, кроме воплей, у вас-то и нет)

Comment: А какие вам нужно аргументы? Вот я скажу, что  обе ваши версии –  это просто ваши фантазии. У вас будут аргументы для доказательства, что это не так.  И почему бы вам не ответить на заданный вопрос, вот бы мы с вами побеседовали.  Я бы это сделала с большим удовольствием, особенно после ваших не вполне вежливых слов.  И ссылок у меня на вас, как я думаю, хватит.  Я имею в виду, в качестве аргументов.  Что касается верхнего регистра, то я выделяю слова для удобства прочтения и понимания.

Comment: @Sharon я пишу: "Запятая требуется по правилу", вы отвечаете: "Какое правило вы имеете в виду? Что тире показывает, к какой части БСП относится вводное слово?" Не замечаете некоторого, кхм-кхм, несоответствия между моей фразой и вашей? Ну, в том, например, что я про Фому (запятую), а вы про Ерёму (тире)?

Comment: 1. Дайте ссылку на правило Розенталя, их у него много.  2. Запятая и тире может быть единым знаком, а может быть независимым сочетанием знаков (слышали, может быть?).  Я-то думала, что вы "в теме", но, возможно, ошиблась.

Comment: @Sharon если бы я имел в виду единый знак, я бы написал про единый знак, а не делил на запятую и тире. Простите, но сегодня у меня настроения нет собачиться.

Comment: Прощаю, но собачиться начали вы, а я с вами разговаривала как с умным и продвинутым человеком.  Так что поговорим в другой раз.

Answer (score 1):

*На «России 1» перестали выходить «Вести в субботу» с Сергеем Брилёвым — **по официальной версии,** он уехал в длительную командировку.*

1. **Тире ставится в БСП**, оно обозначает взаимообусловленные отношения (присоединительные с дополнительным оттенком пояснения). Вводное слово в начале второго предложения обособляется одной запятой.
2. Что касается Розенталя, то он этой темы касается дважды, и поэтому в приложении к ответу я привожу дословные цитаты.
3. Только в редких случаях **приходится сомневаться**, к какой части относится вводное слово. Например: *Собака исчезла, **наверное**, её убили.* Даже в этом предложении ясно, что вводное слово по смыслу относится ко второй части.

Тире же ставится в БСП, так как взаимообусловленные отношения обозначаются обычно двоеточием или тире. Поэтому вполне логично записать: *Собака исчезла — **наверное**, её убили.*

4. А вот тире как **дополнительный знак** вызывает сомнение, так как в БСП именно тире является основным знаком. Да и вообще странно, что один знак не заменяет другой, а "приписывается" к нему. Гораздо логичнее считать запятую и тире **единым знаком,** о чем Розенталь говорит в соответствующей теме. Обычно единый знак подчеркивает расчлененность предложения **на две смысловые части.**
5. Таким образом, можно считать, что для подобных предложений основная запись — это постановка **только тире (или только запятой)**, а запятую и тире следует рассматривать как единый знак (в этом случае делается увеличенная **пауза** и подчеркивается **смысловое деление** предложения).

**Примеры из классики:**

Послал он мне крест – **значит**, меня он любит.

Послышался резкий стук, **должно быть,** сорвалась ставня.

Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, **должно быть**, спешил на водопой.

Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — **должно быть**, хочет зажечь огонь

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

§ 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания, пункт 10 (2)
http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm#ppp_10

Пункт 10. **Тире при вводных словах** (сочетаниях) употребляется в следующих случаях:

2. перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой ставится тире, если вводное слово стоит между частями сложного предложения **и по смыслу может быть отнесено как к предшествующей, так и к последующей его частям:** Собака исчезла, — наверно, её убили (Слепц.); Жена Залесского улыбается длинными бледными губами, куда-то засмотрелась старуха, прищурясь, — верно, в свои, ей одной видимые цветущие сады (Пан.); Но Супругов был занят папиросой, которая почему-то потухла, — должно быть, гильза была рваная (Пан.); Кучерявый… смотрел ему на лоб с выражением отвлечённого интереса, словно решал в уме задачу, — казалось, сейчас вынет из-за уха карандаш, из кармана блокнот и запишет решение (Пан.)[12].

Дополнительный знак препинания может подчеркивать **причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения между частями предложения**: Проверить его слова было трудно, — очевидно, обстоятельства сильно изменились; Появились какие-то новые мысли, — может быть, они никогда уже не повторятся; Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — **должно быть,** хочет зажечь огонь (Гл.).

§ 46. Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении, пункт 2

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152

2. Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями **бессоюзного сложного предложения**, из которых вторая носит **присоединительный характер с каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения** (пояснительным, временным, условно-следственным и др.); нередко эта часть начинается местоименными словами тот, так, такой и т. п.[23]: Но дай-ка мы выедем в поле с тобою, — ты скоро бы пить запросил у меня (Тв.);
3. Запятая и тире ставятся для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной конструкции, для указания, «с одной стороны, **на расчлененность предложения,** а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за этим знаком препинания, делает **структурный поворот** от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, “углом”.